# Flask centralized authentication

Tags: python, authentication, flask

To give some context, I have a Flask app currently hosted on kb.domain.com and plan to develop more internal tools and host then on their corresponding subdomains. Currently, kb.domain.com has its own login system but I’d like this to be centralized on auth.domain.com where managers can have fine grained control over that the users have access to.
I’d also like to be able to eventually branch out into other 3rd party apps if necessary (ex a user needs access to adobe or something).

My question is: how do I implement a centralized authentication system and allow the other apps on separate subdomains to keep up with user data?

I have looked into Flask-Login (my current app uses this), different authentication protocols, etc.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 & OpenID Connect are often used for this.

Adobe offers an SSO solution for their products (source: hi, I work for them). There are [integration guides here](https://helpx.adobe.com/enterprise/using/set-up-identity.html).

But, you may want to start with solutions with existing Flask tutorials, like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python)

> user needs access to adobe or something

I feel like you're referring to ***authorization*** here, not authentication, i.e. if they **can access** "adobe or something" (using `Authorization` HTTP header), vs "are authenticated" (a valid user in your system)

Comment: After doing some research into SAML/SSO it looks like I’ve gotten myself into something that I don’t have the ability or time to mess with. I’d love to create an internal system to handle this stuff and promote consistency across my future apps but I think I’ll reevaluate my approach. Thanks

Comment: Maybe JWT is a valid option?